# How to handle a custom url with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want to handle a custom url with WordPress theme files, for example http://www.example.com/wordpress/login

the question is that how i handle this /login with WordPress theme files like page.php , index.php or a custom template file for this reason, if exists!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin might be useful to you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-logout/

It appears you could create a page called 'Login' which Wordpress would automatically create as http://www.website.com/login/

This plugin appears to be a widget, but I like that it has the ability to manage where a user is re-directed after successful login/logout.

You could register a new widget in functions.php, then call the widget with a conditional to the 'Login' page that way it could be in the main content area rather than look like a widget.

Example:

```
<?php } if ( is_page(9) ) { ?>
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
                || !dynamic_sidebar('login-widget') ) : ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
<?php } else { } ?>
```

My example would assume page 9 = your login Page and 'login-widget' would be the name of the widget you assigned in functions.php